# Installation failed with message Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, apk

I was getting the message

```
> Installation failed with message Failed to establish session.
```

so following some responses to the problem I disabled Instant Run and I started getting

```
> Installation failed with message Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space.
```

I´ve tried rebuilding, cleaning the project, to disable and enable Instant Run and to build APK but nothing solves the problem.

This is my build.gradle (Module:app).

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gabriel.justmeet"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

and this is the build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This started when I modified my RegisterActivity, so it might help

```
package com.example.gabriel.paska;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String REGISTER_URL ="http://justmeet.000webhostapp.com/php/register.php";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME ="username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";
    public static final String KEY_NAME ="name";
    public static final String KEY_AGE="age";
    public static final String REGISTER_SUCCESS ="RegisterSuccess";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME="tech";
    public static final String USERNAME_SHARED_PREF="username";
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF="loggedin";
    private boolean loggedIn=false;
    EditText etAge;
    EditText etName;
    EditText etPassword;
    EditText etUsername;
    Button bRegister;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etAge = findViewById(R.id.etAgeR);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etNameR);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPwordR);
        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsernameR);
        bRegister = findViewById(R.id.btRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                register();
            }
        });
    }
        private void register() {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            final String age = etAge.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(REGISTER_SUCCESS)){

                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = RegisterActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                                editor.putBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                                editor.putString(USERNAME_SHARED_PREF, name);

                                editor.apply();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Failed" + response.trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> prams = new HashMap<>();
                    prams.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                    prams.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                    prams.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                    prams.put(KEY_AGE, age);

                    return prams;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
            if(loggedIn){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there enough space left on your device ? (ram or storage). Otherwise if you're testing on an emulator, try to recreate one...

Answer (score 260):

This issue is about your storage in the emulator. Default AndroidStudio value of 2Gb is not enough for modern Android versions.

[image]

---

***Solution***

**Step 1:** close the emulator.

**Step 2:** Wipe the emulator.

[image]

**Step 3:** change the internal storage and SD Card to **4098MB**.

[image]

**Step 4:** Run the Emulator.

Comment: Step 3 alone working for me!

Comment: I had to wipe the simulator once again after changing its storage size

Answer (score 46):

This is simply the virtual device running out of space. Each install on a virtual device uses up a bit of space each time you run your app. Over time the space fills up until it's all used up. You can increase the space as suggested by some answers - which will work initially but eventually that space will get used up too.

From the virtual device's Settings app you can view how much space you have left. Here you can see that almost a whole GB is used up, but the apps themselves only use 132MB, clearly something is off.

[image]

**Go to the AVD Manager and in the Actions for your device there is the option to 'Wipe Data' - do that.**

[image]

Heading back to the Settings app you can now see that the space is freed up and your app has room to be installed - till the next time it runs out at which point you just repeat this process.

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the Correct answer. It not only tells the root cause, but also how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 22):

that file-system has no space:

```
java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space.
```

the issue is:

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

either remove it, or replace it with:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

---

or make some space on the device / emulator by uninstalled or deleting something -

or simply assign some more megabytes to the virtual SD card.

Comment: Before trying any modifications mentioned do check the space left on device.

Comment: I change the SD-card of AVD Manager into 1000MB,it works

Comment: This is where you set the installLocation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: I deleted 100MB of APKs and apps I'd downloaded/installed on my AVD during testing, and this error went away.

Comment: Looks like installLocation is ignored on newer apis or devices or certain situation as large assets who knows but in my case it's just ignored.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using phone this error comes due to less storage.
Make some space and try again it should work.

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio, open the AVD Manager and edit the problematic emulator. Inside the edit screen, you might need to click on 'Show Advanced Settings'. Scroll down and increase internal memory and SD card memory. After I did this I could install my app again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your storage space on your device which it is running. Try Installing Clearing the space or install it on an emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is trying to install on internal space of your virtual device, and it doesn't have enough space. If you run the emulator, go to config/storage and you'll see you have no space.

Sometimes, the emulator is created with 800Mb of internal space, and Android Oreo (for example) occupies all that space, and it is not possible to install anything.

Furthermore, even when you config your app to "prefer external", the app keep trying to install on internal storeage, so you can not solve the problem with that.

The only solution that worked for me was increasing the internal space of the emulator, you can do that by following one of these options:

A) Go to Android SDK -> ADV Manager, locate your emulator, edit preferences and increase the space, duplicate it, or what you want.

B) Go to the folder with the config of your emulator (In Windows C:/Users/your_user/.android/avd/your_emulator) and edit the *.ini files, you can see values related to space, memory, and so on, just increase that values and save.

Visual Studio 2017 has an aweful integration with Android SDK/ADV Manager, so you need to do this 100% manually, furthermore you don't receive any info or instructions when the error happens, so it's really annoying to fix it :( And it is always the same with the 99% of Xamarin problems!

Answer (score 1):

Create space on your phone or emulator and it should work.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

it simply means the device that you wanna test the app or do debugging on does not have enough space.  So clear off some memory, and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

When running on emulator I found that even when I increased Internal disk space it didn't worked and stayed same size, I had to re-create emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all the apps I ran and got installed on the virtual device and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac I followed the same above procedure, but the settings were different. I didn't have to wipe the device to fix it.

Stop the emulator then choose Edit:

[image]

Then increase the `disk.dataPartition.size` property. It was `800M` for me, I increased it to `4G` for 4 gigabytes.

[image]

Then save and start up the emulator.