# Can't run android or iOS emulator for flutter on vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, emulation

[Error message when running android and iOS emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNmrW.png)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461288/installation-failed-with-message-error-android-os-parcelableexception-java-io

Answer (score 1):

Increase the internal storage of your android emulator

[image: pic]

Comment: Where do i access this from?

Comment: open avd manager; select emulator and click on edit(pencil icon)

Comment: Mine is set to 800MB how much should i change it to?

Comment: try with 1500mb