# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I ran the application, there was no problem at first. Then I made changes in the application and when I  run again, I got this problem. Can anyone who knows the solution help? Thank You

```
 Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 3033347' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:501)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2415)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:949)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:165)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:26141)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:642)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:540)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3329)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4838)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:531)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:447)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:462)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:660)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:499)
... 10 more''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation failed with message Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461288/installation-failed-with-message-error-android-os-parcelableexception-java-io)

Comment: I solved the problem thank you